# Quicksort + Profiling

Tags: haskell, profiling, quicksort

i'm trying to profile a quicksort code. the code is as follows:

```
qsort [] = []
qsort (x:xs) = qsort (filter (< x) xs) ++ [x] ++ qsort (filter (>= x) xs)
```

please help me out!

Comment: This is a very standard haskell quicksort. Have you checked the docs and the wiki?   
http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/profiling.html
http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_profile_a_Haskell_program

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you use GHC, you can enable profiling with the `-prof` flag (probably `-auto-all` and `-caf-all` for more detail).

Then you run your program with `./a.out +RTS -p` to generate the profiling result in `a.out.prof`.

The profile only include the total time and memory spent on each function. Which may not be suitable for you, since there's only one function `qsort`. Compile the program normally and run with `./a.out +RTS -sstderr` may have enough information already.

See

- http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/profiling.html for more profiling options in GHC.
- http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html for how to analyze the profiled info.